# Intermittent blocking mysql query

Tags: mysql, innodb, magento

I have a big problem on our server which host about ten magento website. I make all obvious optimizations like APC for Opcode, APC for cache backend, innodb settings tuning, magento compilation, etc.

The websites load correctly but sometimes, 5-6 times a day, there are MySQL queries “COMMIT” that block the MySQL server and put a very long time to execute (> 500s). Then with all the new incoming connections the server is full loaded with an error “Too many connections”.

Here a screenshot of Phpmyadmin when the problem come: http://imagesia.com/process_2l0n

My my.cnf (without the first default part)

```
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 384M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
table_cache            = 2048
#thread_concurrency     = 10
# 
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_type        = 1
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 64M
# 
# * Logging and Replication
# 
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1

log_error                = /var/log/mysql/error.log

# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
log_slow_queries        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 5
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
# 
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
innodb_log_file_size = 64M
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT

#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem


# limite à partir de laquelle les tables temporaires sont créées sur le DD
tmp_table_size=128M
max_heap_table_size=128M
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: run 'show full processlist' and include that info please

Comment: the screenshot above is the result of `show full processlist` in phpmyadmin

Comment: I don't see any queries there... try 'swho full processlist' and then look at your screenshot and see if it looks the same....

Comment: This is the problem: `show full processlist` and even the mysql-slow.log show me "COMMIT" queries, this is the way innodb and Magento works. I don't know how to track the queries before this commit

Comment: I was hoping there would be more than "COMMIT" queries in that output; for example some query that is blocking those "COMMIT"s . Try enabling slow query log; on the other hand if you have any system trending enabled; check trends to see if anything else hogs system at that time that would explain why MySQL hangs/slows down at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I made many MySQL optimizations with the help of the great utility MySQLtuner and now the problem is gone.